# I want to change sticker value "Sale" to discount percentage

Tags: php, magento, session-variables

Is it possible in `PHP` to print a `variable` that contains `string` and a other variable?
like : file "Lables.php"

class Infortis_Ultimo_Helper_Labels extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

```
public function getLabels($product)
{
    session_start();
    $a = $_SESSION['sdp'];

    $html = '';

    $isNew = false;
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('ultimo/product_labels/new'))
    {   
        $isNew = $this->isNew($product);
    }

    $isSale = false;
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('ultimo/product_labels/sale'))
    {
        $isSale = $this->isOnSale($product);
    }

    if ($isNew == true)
    {
        $html .= '<span class="sticker-wrapper top-left"><span class="sticker new">' . $this->__('New') . '</span></span>';
    }

    if ($isSale == true)
    {

        $html .= '<span class="sticker-wrapper top-right"><span class="sticker sale">'.$a. '</span></span>';

    }

    return $html;
}

/**
 * Check if "new" label is enabled and if product is marked as "new"
 *
 * @return  bool
 */
public function isNew($product)
{
    return $this->_nowIsBetween($product->getData('news_from_date'), $product->getData('news_to_date'));
}

/**
 * Check if "sale" label is enabled and if product has special price
 *
 * @return  bool
 */
public function isOnSale($product)
{
    $specialPrice = number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2);
    $regularPrice = number_format($product->getPrice(), 2);

    if ($specialPrice != $regularPrice)
        return $this->_nowIsBetween($product->getData('special_from_date'), $product->getData('special_to_date'));
    else
        return false;
}

protected function _nowIsBetween($fromDate, $toDate)
{
    if ($fromDate)
    {
        $fromDate = strtotime($fromDate);
        $toDate = strtotime($toDate);
        $now = strtotime(Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->setTime('00:00:00')->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT));

        if ($toDate)
        {
            if ($fromDate <= $now && $now <= $toDate)
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if ($fromDate <= $now)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Actually I want to change the `Sale sticker` with the `discount percentage`. But it is not working in `if condition`. It gives `session variable's value 0`. Any suggestions? I have tried `echo` and `print` in `$html` but not succeeded. I am making changes in `Labels.php` in `magento`.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try var_dump? http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: We are not a "why this code isn't working service" try to elaborate your question better and show us the script you use

Comment: Tried but prob not solved - @aksappy

Comment: If you, just for testing, replace `$a` in `$html` in the `if ($isSale == true)` loop with '30%', do you get the result you eventually want?

Comment: Yup? I am getting it while I am using static $a="30%" but not getting session variable's value @RST

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the code, so I would handle it without using the session.
Something like

```
$saleprice = number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2);
$price = number_format($product->getPrice(), 2);

$percentage =  round((1 - ($saleprice/$price)) * 100);

$a = $percentage." %";
```